# Join two dataframes to get cartesian product

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, cartesian-product

How to join two dataframes and get the cartesian product of all rows in both dataframes.

df1:

```
   values
0       4
1       5
2       6
```

df2:

```
   values
0       7
1       8
2       9
```

Expected Output:

```
   values_x  values_y
0         4         7
1         4         8
2         4         9
3         5         7
4         5         8
5         5         9
6         6         7
7         6         8
8         6         9
```

Comment: Nopes , doesnt answers the question

Comment: It is called cross join, check dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dummy column to merge on:

```
df1.assign(dummy=1).merge(df2.assign(dummy=1), on='dummy', how='outer').drop('dummy', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   values_x  values_y
0         4         7
1         4         8
2         4         9
3         5         7
4         5         8
5         5         9
6         6         7
7         6         8
8         6         9
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'outer', left_on = 'value1', right_on = 'value2')
```

Comment: `KeyError: 'value2'`

Comment: I tried this one but in some of the output you will get null values

Comment: then you might have null values in one or both the dataframe.
can you check with info() functionality?